# Need help with drop down menus

Tags: html, javascript, css

I'm trying to create a website that has multiple buttons that will cause a drop down menu to appear. Each drop down menu will have different things that you can from. So far I'm not having any luck. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using CSS, Java and HTML for the button right now. I have the CSS and JavaScript in a separate file. Below I have listed all the coding in each doc. I have tried changing; classes to ids, ids to classes, the names to different things. Either the first button opens, regardless of which one I click on, or nothing happens, no drop down or anything. Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

HTML Doc

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Title Here</title>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
        <meta name="FORMATTER" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
        <meta name="keywords" content="content here">
        <meta name="description" content="Contains information on strategies .">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Subcode/CSS/index.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Subcode/CSS/dropdownbuttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script src="Subcode/Java/button.js"></script>
        <script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/r20160913/ca-pub-4807457957392508.js"></script><script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/r20160913/ca-pub-4807457957392508.js"></script>
        <link rel="search" href="Subcode/xhtml/search.xml" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Open Search">
    </head>
    <body background="Images/Background/Finished/bg1.jpg">      
        <div class="sleft">
            <div class="webDD">
                <button onclick="webInfo()" class="webDropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="webDD" class="webDDCon">
                    <a href="about.html">About the Site</a><br>
                    <a href=""></a><br>
                    <a href=""></a><br> 
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Subcode/CSS/dropdownbutton.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>  
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>  
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="mbody">

        </div>
        <div class="bottom">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Doc

```
/* Dropdown Button A */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

JavaScript Doc

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's because you're using the same `id` for all of the dropdown menus, and you can only use an `id` once. So when you toggle `.show` on `#myDropdown`, it always targets the first one since the browser doesn't expect there to be more than one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution.  Like @MichaelCoker said, one of the problems was the reuse of the same ID for multiple elements.

Here are the changes I made:

- Unique IDs for each dropdown (`myDropdown1`, etc.)
- Passing `this` into the `onclick` function to differentiate between the elements

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
    btn.nextSibling.nextSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button A */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Title Here</title>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
        <meta name="FORMATTER" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
        <meta name="keywords" content="content here">
        <meta name="description" content="Contains information on strategies .">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Subcode/CSS/index.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Subcode/CSS/dropdownbuttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script src="Subcode/Java/button.js"></script>
        <script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/r20160913/ca-pub-4807457957392508.js"></script><script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/r20160913/ca-pub-4807457957392508.js"></script>
        <link rel="search" href="Subcode/xhtml/search.xml" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Open Search">
    </head>
    <body background="Images/Background/Finished/bg1.jpg">      
        <div class="sleft">
            <div class="webDD">
                <button onclick="webInfo()" class="webDropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="webDD" class="webDDCon">
                    <a href="about.html">About the Site</a><br>
                    <a href=""></a><br>
                    <a href=""></a><br> 
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Subcode/CSS/dropdownbutton.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>  
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>  
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown4" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown5" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown6" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown7" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">A button</button>
                <div id="myDropdown8" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=""></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="mbody">

        </div>
        <div class="bottom">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that for this code to work in IE, you'll need to use `.msMatchesSelector()` instead of `.matches()`.